# Call to gtk_main_quit causes "segmentation fault" in assembler code

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, gtk, gtk3

I'm learning assembler (FASM) and I have weird problem, whenever i want to call gtk_main_quit() it always ends with "segmentation fault".

Why call gtk_main_quit causes segmentation fault?

## test.asm

```
format ELF

extrn gtk_init
extrn gtk_main
extrn gtk_main_quit
extrn gtk_window_new
extrn gtk_widget_show
extrn g_signal_connect_data

public main

on_window_close:
    call gtk_main_quit ; <- segmentation fault
    ret

main:
    push 0
    push 0
    call gtk_init
    add esp, 8

    push 0
    call gtk_window_new
    add esp, 4
    mov [window_handle], eax

    push 0
    push 0
    push 0
    push on_window_close
    push on_close_signal
    push [window_handle]
    call g_signal_connect_data
    add esp, 24

    push [window_handle]
    call gtk_widget_show
    add esp, 8

    call gtk_main

window_handle dd 0
on_close_signal db 'destroy', 0
```

## makefile

```
all:
    ~/apps/fasm/fasm ./test.asm
    gcc -o test test.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch lol, it helped, thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making function calls always ensure that you restore the stack properly after a call. Your code does this:

```
push [window_handle]
call gtk_widget_show
add esp, 8
```

You push one *DWORD* onto the stack as a parameter which is correct, but after your call to `gtk_widget_show` you add 8 to *ESP*. Since you only pushed 4 bytes on the stack, this restores *ESP* improperly. A side effect will be that the return address of the function `main` will now be in the wrong place which would likely yield a segmentation fault when your `main` function returns. The code should have been:

```
push [window_handle]
call gtk_widget_show
add esp, 4
```

That brings up the second issue. Your code:

```
    call gtk_main

window_handle dd 0
on_close_signal db 'destroy', 0
```

After `gtk_main` returns it will start executing whatever instructions appear in memory after. In this case it happens to be some variables and whatever else is in memory. Since the *C* runtime called your function `main` like any other function, you should use `ret` to return back to the *C* runtime and let it shutdown your program cleanly.

The code would look like:

```
    call gtk_main
    ret

window_handle dd 0
on_close_signal db 'destroy', 0
```

Comment: @BPS: Instead of `call` / `ret`, you should tailcall optimize this to  `jmp gtk_main`

Answer (score 1):

The call to `gtk_main_quit` causes `gtk_main` to return, execution continues after the call executing the window handle, and possibly the text "destroy". It would be hard to predict exactly what happens.

Add `ret` after `call gtk_main`.

Comment: Good point, but after adding "ret" after "call gtk_main", segmentation fault still remains.